# How to Left Join from an un-nested table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join, unnest

I had written a code to create more records from 1 record based on some conditions. For example: If the user purchased a monthly package, the table will create records for each week until the Date Ended.

From this:

```
Order ID|Date Purchased| Date Ended| Package|
   001  | 2019-1-1     | 2019-2-1  | 1Month |
```

To this:

```
   Order ID|Date Purchased| Date Ended| Package| Date Weekly
      001  |2019-1-1      | 2019-2-1  | 1Month |  2019-1-1
      001  |2019-1-1      | 2019-2-1  | 1Month |  2019-1-8 
      001  |2019-1-1      | 2019-2-1  | 1Month |  2019-1-15
      001  |2019-1-1      | 2019-2-1  | 1Month |  2019-1-23
```

The question is how do I perform a Left Join of the 2nd table with the 1st table by Order ID? If there are additional records I wanted to join? For example, Order ID 002, 003 etc. Thanks in advance :)

Here's my code

```
SELECT
*
FROM 
(
SELECT
*,
DATE(PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', date_purchased)) AS date_purchased, --Transform datetime to time
DATE(PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', date_ended)) AS date_ended
FROM
`database_123`
),UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(date_purchased, date_ended, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) AS date_weekly
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your post

```
SELECT
*
FROM 
(
    SELECT
    *,
    DATE(PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', date_purchased)) AS date_purchased, --Transform datetime to time
    DATE(PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', date_ended)) AS date_ended
    FROM
    `database_123`
),UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(date_purchased, date_ended, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) AS date_weekly 
LEFT JOIN your_first_table ft on date_weekly.orderId = ft.orederId
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider to use [*CROSS JOIN*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#cross-join) function in order to combine records from two tables within joining each record from rows set across `UNNEST()` with the single row from the source table. Unlike the `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN` doesn't establish a relationship between the joined tables, however it contains `order_id` column value for each generated by `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY` record.

For example, as per given below test dataset:

```
WITH
  table_1 AS (
  SELECT
    "001" AS order_id,
    "2019-01-01 00:00:00" AS date_purch,
    "2019-02-01 00:00:00" AS date_end,
    "1Month" AS package
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    "002" AS order_id,
    "2019-03-01 00:00:00" AS date_purch,
    "2019-05-01 00:00:00" AS date_end,
    "2Months" AS package)
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    order_id,
    DATE(PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
        date_purch)) AS date_purchased,
    DATE(PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
        date_end)) date_ended,
    package
  FROM
    table_1)
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(date_purchased, date_ended, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) AS date_weekly
ORDER BY
  order_id
```

Find more examples [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening-arrays).